# Animate a point, ol.layer.Vector or VectorContext

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to animate a point along a path. I saw the [Marker Animation Example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html) that uses a [VectorContext](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.render.canvas.Immediate.html) to render the point. I also have a source in my map that can contain this point and I can modify the geometry every few milliseconds. Is there a preferred method and why? Is there performance differences between the two methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance will be better when using the VectorContext. But for a single animated geometry you probably won't notice any difference. The overhead from modifying the geometry is the event chain that gets triggered: geometry notifies feature, feature notifies layer, layer requests map redraw.